# Select multiple rows in table by pressing control key and selecting each row. How can I apply this on angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I apply this in my angular 2 project. I have a table that contains data. I want the rows of the table to be selectable. Multiple selection of table rows are done by hold pressing control key and selecting each rows. I was able to do the selecting of 1 row but having a hard time implementing the multiple selection using control key. I want to transfer data from table to the array.

HTML

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let person of people (click)="addThisPersonToArray(person)" [class.active]="isPersonSelected(person)">
        <td>{{person.id}}</td>
        <td>{{person.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{person.lastName}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In my component

```
export class PersonTableComponent{
    selectedPersonArray = [];
    people = [];
    isKeyPressed: boolean: false;

    constructor(public person: PersonListService {
       this.people = person.fetchData();
    }


    addThisPersonToArray(person: Person){
       if(this.isKeyPressed ==  false){
           this.selectedPersonArray =[]; //clear array coz ctrl not pressed it selectedPerson should only be one.
       }
       this.selectedPersonArray.push(person);
    }

    //check if person exist in the array return if true otherwise false. 
    // return of true will make the row active thus changing the color and 
    // indicating it is selected

    isPersonSelected(person: Person){
       if(this.selectedPersonArray.indexOf(store) != -1){  
            return true;
       }
       return false;
   }


  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
    handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.ctrlkey) {
         this.isKeyPressed= true;
    }
    else{
         this.isKeyPressed = false;
   }











}
```

In my html, the table contains list of persons. The click event accept person as parameter in which I will push into to the selectedPersonArray. If control key is not pressed only one person can be selected and push to selectedPersonArray. If control is pressed all selected person will be pushed to selectedPersonArray.

Comment: Thank you so much @yurzui. You're my hero. haha. I've been trying to implementing this one since yesterday. Thanks for your help. Just want to ask another one. I also want to implement the shift key selection. How can I implement this in my angular

Comment: @yurzui can you put it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of `document:keydown` handler and use only one handler to do it working.

**view**

```
(click)="addThisPersonToArray(person)"
```

component

```
toggleItemInArr(arr, item) {
  const index = arr.indexOf(item);
  index === - 1 ? arr.push(item) : arr.splice(index, 1);
}

addThisPersonToArray(person: any, event) {
  if (!event.ctrlKey) {
    this.selectedPersonArray = [];
  }

  this.toggleItemInArr(this.selectedPersonArray, person);
}

isPersonSelected(person: any) {
  return this.selectedPersonArray.indexOf(person) !== -1);
}
```

See also **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/vKpEQgi9vHLFW025YeaO?p=preview)**

Comment: I also want to add multiple selection of rows using shift key. How can I implement that with your code?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use PrimeNG DataTable module for this purpose:

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/selection

Comment: I'm now using it @Mario Petrovic. It's great but I just to ask can I also implement multiple selection using SHIFT KEY in primeNG?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I see that they don't expose setting for pressed key. That would be a nice feature :D

Comment: :( in my project multiple selection using shift key is needed. I guess I should now use the plain table or is their any other option besides primesNG?

Comment: No, sorry. I see that all ng2-data-table modules are either obsolete or dont support multiselect :(